# Avoiding rate limitaton by 3rd party API in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, queue

**API Docs Description:**

> Handle Newly Implemented Rate Limits:
>
> There is a rate limit of 4
> requests per second. If you go over this limit you will receive a
> response with status code 429 Too Many Requests.
>
> You are able to have up to 8 open requests at any moment in time. This
> can occur if requests take longer than 1 second to respond when
> multiple requests are being made.

I have tried using `better-queue` to queue my calls, but whatever combination I try to do I am not able to schedule 4 api calls per second with max concurrent calls staying at 8 if previous calls don't resolve.

I couldn't get it to work as above, but this is my testing code:

```
const Queue = require('better-queue');

function randomNumber(max, min) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

let queueCount = 0
const q = new Queue(function (input, cb) {

  console.log('@@@ task started -->', input)
  const result = input

  setTimeout(() => cb(null, result), randomNumber(4000, 2000))
}, {
  concurrent: 4,
  // filo: true,
  // batchSize: 4,
  // batchDelay: 1000,
  // batchDelayTimeout: 1000,
  // afterProcessDelay: 1000,
})

q.push({ id: ++queueCount })
q.push({ id: ++queueCount })
q.push({ id: ++queueCount })
q.push({ id: ++queueCount })
q.push({ id: ++queueCount })
q.push({ id: ++queueCount })
q.push({ id: ++queueCount })
q.push({ id: ++queueCount })
q.push({ id: ++queueCount })
q.push({ id: ++queueCount })

q.on('task_finish', function (taskId, result, stats) {
  console.log('@@@ task_finish <--', taskId, result, stats)
})
q.on('task_failed', function (taskId, err, stats) {
  console.log('### task_failed', taskId, err, stats)
})

q.on('empty', function (){
  console.log('@@@ queue empty')
})
q.on('drain', function (){
  console.log('@@@ queue drain')
})
```

which produced below results:

```
@@@ task started --> { id: 1 }
@@@ task started --> { id: 2 }
@@@ task started --> { id: 3 }
@@@ task started --> { id: 4 }
@@@ task_finish <-- 2 { id: 2 } { elapsed: 2454 }
@@@ task started --> { id: 5 }
@@@ task_finish <-- 4 { id: 4 } { elapsed: 2483 }
@@@ task started --> { id: 6 }
@@@ task_finish <-- 1 { id: 1 } { elapsed: 2669 }
@@@ task started --> { id: 7 }
@@@ task_finish <-- 3 { id: 3 } { elapsed: 2945 }
@@@ task started --> { id: 8 }
@@@ task_finish <-- 5 { id: 5 } { elapsed: 4792 }
@@@ task started --> { id: 9 }
@@@ task_finish <-- 7 { id: 7 } { elapsed: 5119 }
@@@ task started --> { id: 10 }
@@@ task_finish <-- 6 { id: 6 } { elapsed: 5533 }
@@@ task_finish <-- 8 { id: 8 } { elapsed: 6414 }
@@@ task_finish <-- 9 { id: 9 } { elapsed: 7324 }
@@@ task_finish <-- 10 { id: 10 } { elapsed: 8876 }
@@@ queue empty
@@@ queue drain
```

It keeps concurrents requests at 4, which I need at 8 but to send 4 requests per second. looking for a solution, any help is appreciated.

Comment: "but whatever combination I try to do " put the code of what you are trying so people can know where you are going wrong. right now, the question is just incomplete, which makes harder for the community to help you.

Comment: @Jay I have added the sample code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I did some research to find a good solution to the problem I asked above and I came across this npm package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrate
It does exactly what I need, keeping the concurrent requests to 8 and rate limiting 4 requests per second; here is my code:

```
// require qrate library
const qrate = require('qrate')

function randomNumber(max, min) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// mark the start time of this script
const start = new Date().getTime();

// worker function that calls back after 100ms - 10000ms
const worker = function(data, done) {

  // your worker code goes here
  // 'data' contains the queue to work on
  // call 'done' when finished.
 
 
  // output a message including a timestamp
  console.log('Processing', data, '@', new Date().getTime() - start, 'ms')

  // call the 'done' function
  setTimeout(done, randomNumber(10000, 100))
};

// create a queue with default properties (concurrency = 1, rateLimit = null)
// using our 'worker' function to process each item in the queue
const q = qrate(worker, 8, 4)

// add things to the queue
for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  q.push({ i: i });
}

q.drain = () => {
  // all of the queue items have been processed
  console.log('@@@ queue drain', '@', new Date().getTime() - start, 'ms')
}
```

which produces below results:

```
Processing { i: 1 } @ 54 ms
Processing { i: 2 } @ 56 ms
Processing { i: 3 } @ 56 ms
Processing { i: 4 } @ 56 ms
Processing { i: 5 } @ 1002 ms
Processing { i: 6 } @ 1003 ms
Processing { i: 7 } @ 1003 ms
Processing { i: 8 } @ 1003 ms
Processing { i: 9 } @ 3664 ms
Processing { i: 10 } @ 4308 ms
Processing { i: 11 } @ 4941 ms
Processing { i: 12 } @ 5570 ms
Processing { i: 13 } @ 6660 ms
Processing { i: 14 } @ 7254 ms
Processing { i: 15 } @ 7479 ms
Processing { i: 16 } @ 8261 ms
Processing { i: 17 } @ 9172 ms
Processing { i: 18 } @ 9975 ms
Processing { i: 19 } @ 10214 ms
Processing { i: 20 } @ 10406 ms
@@@ queue drain @ 17445 ms
```

Cheers!